# columns resizing differently on mobile

Tags: css, responsive

i have an issue with 5 image columns where upon re-sizing to mobile, the sizes are different in 2 columns from the other 3. This works for landscape mobile but portrait looks awful.
Is there a way I can make sure the columns are always uniform in size? 
Looking for some css code to add if possible.
http://www.temp.lpwgroup.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/ it's the client images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
    .column-narrow.col5 .client {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if i've done it right, works ok on mobile but it makes the logos 100% on desktop though